# Docker Machine - generic driver does not support start

Tags: go, driver, docker-machine

I try to use `Docker Machine` on a host and have got following error:

> generic driver does not support start

This script is working perfectly on another hosts. I have looked into the problem, but haven't find other that this: https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/master/drivers/generic/generic.go
Which preferences should I check to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can't you just use docker toolbox?

Comment: It is a Linux based environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which driver are you using on the other hosts? the generic driver is not really a machine driver (controlling a machine with start/stop etc), but a generic interface to use (a subset of) docker-machine commands with an existing virtual machine or even physical host. (From the docs: "Create machines using an existing VM/Host with SSH." https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/, where the word "Create" is a little misleading.)

So the question remains, what is your setup exactly? What drivers are you using on the other hosts, for what purpose are you using docker-machine on the other hosts and on that host with the generic driver?

Comment: This host is part of `GRID5000` clusters, so cannot write exact config.

Comment: so you have a cluster of physical hosts and want to provision virtual machines for docker on them?

Comment: Yes, these hosts are allocated dinamically.